# Which of the following use of anchor is correct in regex using grep?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Both of the below commands gives the same output,
however which one is the correct method to use it?

```
grep ^'\<that\>' file.txt
```

Searches for the line which has that as the first word

```
grep '^\<that\>' file.txt
```

Same output as the previous one.

Whats the difference in placing ^ anchor before the quotes or inside the quotes?
Which one is the appropriate one?

Answer (score 1):

If you put the "^" outside the quotes, your shell could interpret it as a redirection.  Quoting it avoids that problem.  That is considered obsolete, but you can find it mentioned, e.g., in the [changelog for fish](https://fishshell.com/release_notes.html):

> The caret **`^`** now only does a stderr redirection if it is the first character of a token, making git users happy #168

Further reading:

- [Characteristical common properties of the traditional Bourne shells](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/common.html)
  where Sven Mascheck notes:

> You can use the caret, **`'^'`**, as replacement for the pipe symbol, '|'. This origins from the main predecessor, the Thompson shell. (An exception is the Version 8 shell, which is not widely distributed, where this feature was removed while cleaning up the design.)

Comment: What shells use `^` for redirection? Is this a fish thing?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any difference between the commands. They both run exactly the same thing:

```
$ set -x  ## turn on debugging info

$ /bin/grep ^'\<that\>' file.txt
+ /bin/grep '^\<that\>' file.txt

$ /bin/grep '^\<that\>' file.txt
+ /bin/grep '^\<that\>' file.txt
```

As you can see above, both versions end up running the exact same thing.

That said, as a general rule, it is always safer to keep your entire regular expression inside the quotes, so use:

```
/bin/grep '^\<that\>' file.txt
```

While in this case it makes no difference, it makes a huge difference if your regular expression includes a character that is significant for the shell. For example:

```
grep ;'foo' file
```

Here, the shell will interpret the `;` as a control character and run two commands: `grep` (with no arguments) and `'foo' file`.